# How to return HTTP response directly from Interceptor without sending it to server using http interceptor package

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Hey I'm using [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) package to handle my request and response. Here I want to bypass the request by giving a response from the client iteself without sending it to the server.

We have a solution in dio

```
Dio dio = Dio();
  MockInterceptor mockInterceptor = MockInterceptor();

  // Add the mock interceptor
  dio.interceptors.add(mockInterceptor);

  // Define the mock response
  when(mockInterceptor.onRequest(any)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async {
    return Response(data: {'message': 'Mock response'}, statusCode: 200);
  });
```

**Do we have the same feature like this in http_intecpetor as well?**